# Get query string from href attribute via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building an interface that uses AJAX with an HTML fallback. I'm setting up all my `<a>` tags to work without AJAX first, and if Javascript is enabled, each link will have an "onclick" function attached to it that sends the same exact query string to a different page on my server.

My original link will look like this:

```
<a class="ajax" href="http://example.com/page?key1=value1&key2=value2">Link</a>
```

How do I retrieve "key1=value1&key2=value2" as a string from the above href link via Javascript? I will be making AJAX requests that look like `http://example.com/ajax?key1=value1&key2=value2`.

Comment: Can you share your solution so far?

Comment: I'm getting the string from the link with `var link = document.getElementsByClassName("ajax")[0].href;`. Using the answers below (both have what I needed), I apply `var x = link.indexOf('?');` to target the beginning of the query, then `var query = x >= 0 ? link.substring(x + 1) : null;` to populate a new variable with the isolated query string.

Comment: I'll be creating a link handler like T.J. Crowder describes for my actual project, but for this example, getElementsByClassName() works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a `click` handler either to individual links:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var index;
for (index = 0; index < links.length; ++index) {
    links.onclick = linkClickHandler;
}
function linkClickHandler() {
    var x = this.href.indexOf('?');
    var query = x >= 0 ? this.href.substring(x + 1) : null;
    if (query) {
        // Do the ajax thing...
        // (your code here)
        // ...and prevent the link from being followed
        return false;
    }
}
```

...or (and this is probably better) to `document` itself:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var target, x, query;

    e = e || window.event;
    target = e.target;
    if (target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
        x = target.indexOf('?');
        query = x >= 0 ? target.substring(x + 1) : null;
        if (query) {
            // Do the ajax thing...
            // (your code here)
            // ...and prevent the link from being followed
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

In either case, on modern browsers you might want to use `addEventListener` rather than `onclick`, and call `preventDefault` on the event object. But IE8 still uses `attachEvent` rather than `addEventListener`.

(`return false;` from an old-fashioned DOM0 event handler like `onclick` prevents the default action of the event; [details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html).)

Comment: Great! The part that was specifically looking for was the combination of `target.indexOf('?')` and `target.substring(x + 1)`. Everything else you provided will just make my job that much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Looking at your comments on other answers, this is what you need

```
linkElement.search.substr(1)
```

---

## The answer...

You can access the same properties you would with `window.location`.

For querystring of a href it would be `(document.querySelector('a#mylink')).search`

#### Other accessible properties

```
.hash
.host
.hostname
.href
.origin
.pathname
.port
.protocol
.search
```

### In your case, for all the links on a page use this little script

**I am only selecting links with actual hrefs.*

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href]'), function(el) {
    var queryString = el.search.substr(1)
    el.onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault() // don't redirect and stuff...
        // do the magic here with the queryString
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample code should be enough to help you parse what you need.  Note that I added an id to the anchor to make it easy to access.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function parse() {
  var el = document.getElementById("foo");
  var href = el.href;
  var pos = href.indexOf("?");
  alert(href.substring(pos+1));
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white" onLoad="parse()">
<a id="foo" class="ajax" href="http://example.com/page?key1=value1&key2=value2">Link</a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This, too, includes the info I was looking for, `indexOf("?")` and `substring(pos+1)`. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  I answered exactly what the person asked for and he even commented that he appreciated the response.